# How to merge big data of csv files column wise into a single csv file using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have lots of big data csv files in terms of countries and I want to merge their column in a single csv file, furthermore, each file has 'Year' as an index and having same in terms of length and numbers. You can see below is a given example of a Japan.csv file.

If anyone can help me please let me know. Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your goal?

Comment: wanna merge all csv file bro! but each csv file have same as above mentioned picture except country name.

Comment: I only see one...

Comment: I have in my directory around 200 csv file. how can I show you?

Comment: Am i getting on the right track with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
l = []
path = 'path/to/directory/'
csvs = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
for i in csvs:
    df = pd.read_csv(i, index_col=None, header=0)
    l.append(df)
df = pd.concat(l, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It goes over each file name, reads it and combines everything into one df. You can export this df to csv or do whatever with it. gl.

```
import pandas as pd

def combine_csvs_into_one_df(names_of_files):
    one_big_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for file in names_of_files:
        try:
            content = pd.read_csv(file)
        except PermissionError:
            print (file,"was not found")
            continue

        one_big_df = pd.concat([one_big_df,content])
        print (file," added!")

    print ("------")
    print ("Finished")

    return one_big_df
```